# Greatest common divisors

Tags: number-theory

If $\gcd(a,p)=1$ where $p$ is an odd prime then $\gcd(4a,p)=1.$ Any hint??

Comment: What have you tried?  How many possible values are there for $\gcd(4a,p)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ an odd prime number. Let $k\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $k\mid p$ and $k\mid 4a$. In particular, if $k\neq 1$, then $k=p$. If $p\mid 4a$ then $p\mid a$, and thus $\gcd(a,p)\neq 1$. Therefore, $\gcd(4a,p)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is given that $p$ is odd prime so $gcd(4,p)$ is $1$. Now its also given that $gcd(a,p)=1$ so we can conclude from above two gcd relation that $gcd(4a,p) =1$ as
 $4$ and $p$ was not having any common factor other than $1$ so do a and p so $4a$ and $p$ are also not having any common factor other than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $d=gcd(4a,p)$, then $d/p$. So $d=1$ or $d=p$ . But, if $d=p$ then $p/4a$ , given that p is an odd prime $(gcd(p,2)=1)$.

Now using euclid’s lemma, we can conclude that $p/a$, contradiction with $gcd(a,p)=1$.

so $d=1$.